# Are workflows inherrited when creating a site template?

Tags: workflow, site-template, template

I just created a site template and the new site.
I cannot view the workflows when clicking 'manage workflows with nin tex worklow' but when I click 'workflows' in my item menu I get all the workflows and I can start them.

Can someone explain this behavior to me? 
Thanks!